# Maps API Android - Polylines adapt to street

Tags: android, api, navigation, maps, polyline

First of all, sorry for my English (I'm Spanish).

I'm making an andorid app that uses the Maps API. I want to draw with the polylines the way from one point to another (as in a marathon) and I want that the polylines adapt to the street, i mean that between two points don't goes through a building. (I want it as in navigation)
I show you the problem with the image.

It breaks through the buildings
[image: It breaks through the buildings]
`

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(36.71924076644312, -4.421350873626579))
        .add(new LatLng(36.71952353679909, -4.420758105434288))  
        .add(new LatLng(36.71995225115975, -4.421356238044609))  
        .add(new LatLng(36.72021373552526, -4.4201492439879075))  
        .add(new LatLng(36.72153026434974, -4.42017070168049));

Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
        polyline.setGeodesic(true);
        polyline.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: you should add your source code also

Comment: editted! Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use Directions API with Java client library to draw the route between your source and destination points,
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

2) Second option is, you can reduce the frequency of location points and draw polyline between those points to get more accurate route